# How to add contact seller button in product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, buttons

can someone help me with this issue ?
I want to add a button in my product page and name it (contact seller) and I want to link this button to the seller page. how can I do it ?

here is a screenshot for what i'm looking to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook to add custom button in the single product page in WooCommerce. Please check following example. Custom link added and `button` class is given to display it like a button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpso_add_seller_button', 15 );
function wpso_add_seller_button() {
    echo '<a href="https://example.com" class="button">Contact Seller</a>';
}
```